# Cleanly writing numerous conditions against an optional input

Tags: c#

Suppose the user can enter all or part of a date { Day, Month, Year }

Each field is optional. They may enter just the day, or just the month, or the day and the month etc.

I then loop through a list of dates, and check if the dates match based on what the user entered (and depending on how much of it they entered):

```
Input: {D = 20} CheckDate: 2015/01/20 = true
Input: {D = 20} CheckDate: 2015/01/15 = false
Input: {D = 20, Month = 6} CheckDate: 2015/06/20 = true
Input: {D = 20, Month = 6} CheckDate: 2015/01/20 = false
Input: {D = 20, Month = 6, Year = 2016} CheckDate: 2016/06/20 = true
Input: {D = 20, Month = 6, Year = 2016} CheckDate: 2015/06/20 = false
```

I can achieve this logic by checking every possible combination of input date against the check date like so:

```
    private bool IsInputDateMatch(InputDate inputDate, DateTime date)
    {
        if (inputDate.Day != 0 && inputDate.Month != 0 && inputDate.Year != 0)
            return date.Day == inputDate.Day && date.Month == inputDate.Month && date.Year == inputDate.Year;

        if(inputDate.Day !=0 && inputDate.Month != 0)
            return date.Day == inputDate.Day && date.Month == inputDate.Month;
        if (inputDate.Day != 0 && inputDate.Year != 0)
            return date.Day == inputDate.Day && date.Year == inputDate.Year;
        if (inputDate.Month != 0 && inputDate.Year != 0)
            return date.Month == inputDate.Month && date.Year == inputDate.Year;

        if (inputDate.Day != 0)
            return date.Day == inputDate.Day;
        if (inputDate.Month != 0)
            return date.Month == inputDate.Month;
        if (inputDate.Year != 0)
            return date.Year == inputDate.Year;

        return true;
    }
```

But this isn't very elegant.

When you encounter a logic situation like this (checking multiple conditions based on how much of something is provided), how might it be written in a clean approach? Can I perhaps generate the conditions required dynamically?

Comment: There is an expression, [garbage in garbage out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out). I think that might apply here especially when you allow only parts of a date to be entered. Why not focus on changing the code where the data is submitted (whatever that entry stream is) and adding validation there to ensure that partial required fields are not allowed (like entering only a month when a whole date is expected)?

Comment: You can create mappings in some XML file and then invoke certain logic based on the outcome of this mapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your code as follows:

```
private bool IsInputDateMatch(InputDate inputDate, DateTime date)
{
    if (inputDate.Day != 0 && date.Day != inputDate.Day)
        return false;

    if (inputDate.Month != 0 && date.Month != inputDate.Month)
        return false;

    return inputDate.Year == 0 || date.Year == inputDate.Year;
}
```

Comment: Well spotted along with Marko's answer. I guess the pattern is: if the input field is provided, check the logic for that field (no need to consider combinations).

Answer (score 1):

This should be a bit simpler. Check all parts that were provided and if any is wrong then it's a no match. If no part is left then it is  surely a match.

```
private bool IsInputDateMatch(InputDate inputDate, DateTime date)
    {
        if (inputDate.Day != 0 && date.Day != inputDate.Day)
            return false;
        if (inputDate.Month != 0 && date.Month != inputDate.Month)
            return false;
        if (inputDate.Year != 0 && date.Year != inputDate.Year)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Additionally you might wanna check if any part is submittied at all, but I expect you'll check this before submitting.

Comment: Yes, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Create the method in the `InputDate` class. It is still not very elegant but you only need to write this once.

```
class InputDate
{
   public bool IsMatch(DateTime date)
   {
      // real implementation here
      return true;
   }
}
```

You'll probably want to UnitTest the heck out of methods like that. The examples you provided in the question would all be good test candidates. And each time you find a bug, add a new test with that case.

Once you have the tests in place, you can easily refactor the method body while ensuring that everything still works as expected.